# Import.io returns empty columns for javascript enabled api

Tags: import.io

I have searched here and couldnt find any answers. Some columns of an import.io api is not returning any data. These data is behind javascript, but, during training it returns data, but, during bulk extract or crawling, the column is empty. I mailed the import.io support, they asked me to post my question here. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide more information. What is the url you are extracting from? what is the guid of your extractor?

Comment: The url is 
https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1410842311/the-future-is-now-volume-two
I was trying to extract "days to go" value and the end date provided after "This project will be funded on".

GUID is a7e3f2b7-6a52-4310-bf3a-15721e14ae53

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in the HTML of the page you can see an attributes on the part of the html near where "days to go" is displayed, even without JS.

e.g:

`data-hours-remaining="532.6704760581918"`

and:

`data-end_time="2016-04-13T16:00:00-04:00"`

I believe this corresponds to the "days to go" text.

Use a custom xpath e.g: `.//*[@id='project_duration_data']/@data-hours-remaining` to get the data you want from these attributes. You can then post-process them into whatever format you want; days, weeks etc..

Comment: Thanks Bam4d. I tried //span[@id='project_duration_data']/@data-hours-remaining and [@id='project_duration_data']/@data-end_time and it gave me results, even though its not the exact data i wanted. I used some regex to trim the data. Thank you.